# Should Page Objects Return Page Objects?

Tags: java, webdriver, pageobjects

We're currently working on building up a good test frame in our company. It's for a medium-to-large-sized webapp, perhaps with a couple dozen pages. We're currently writing mostly WebDriver Selenium UI-based tests.

We are trying to decide on some coding standards, and one thing we're discussing is whether to use Page Objects (PO) that always return PO (even if the page is the same), only return PO when you leave the current page for a new one, or even to not return PO. I've always thought returning PO is a key feature of the PO design pattern, but I may be incorrect about this.

Basically, we're trying to decide between the following patterns:

```
class SomePage {
     // constructor
     public SomePage(Driver) { //... } 

     // always return a page object
     public SomePage fillInTextField(String val){
          // details
          return new SomePage(driver);

     // only return a PO if it's a different page
     public void fillInTextField(String val){
          // details
          return;

     }
```

Is one preferable over the other?

Comment: Don't return a new SomePage but instead do something with the val and then `return this;`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of style.

Using:

```
class SomePage {
    ...
    // always return a page object
    public SomePage fillInTextField(String val){
         ...
         return this; // Note: NOT "new SomePage(driver)"
    }
}
```

allows you to write things like:

```
SomePage somePage = HoweverYouGetASomePage();
NextPage nextPage = somePage.fillInTextField1("value1").fillInTextField2("value2").submit();
```

Using:

```
class SomePage {
    ...
    // only return a PO if it's a different page
    public void fillInTextField(String val){
        ...
        return;
    }
}
```

forces you to write things like:

```
SomePage somePage = HoweverYouGetASomePage();
somePage.fillInTextField1("value1");
somePage.fillInTextField2("value2");
NextPage nextPage = somePage.submit();
```

Which one you like depends on ... which one you like.  But if you like being **able** to write the former, you need to **always** return the page object.

Comment: Of course! `return this;` could be a happy medium here. Thanks for pointing out the obvious!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that don't return same page objects if you are on the same page and *state of the page is not changing*. You would return new page objects if you are navigating from one page to another.  It wouldn't make sense to return the same object when lets say you want to get some text or get a selected option from a page, since essentially nothing changed. If the state of the page is changing, then you would need to return the new page object otherwise you may likely face `StaleElementException`. In [google docs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects), If you notice the LoginPage, `getErrorMessage()` does not return the same page object back

A little off from your original question, but I would recommend to use [PageFactory](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory), if you already aren't and are in the process of formalizing standards.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it extremely maintainable to do this.  Especially with Java 8.  Using default methods in Java 8, components and widgets now become Mixins.  By always returning a Page, you end up with test cases that look like this:

```
public class HomePageITest {
  @Test
  public we_should_be_able_to_search_from_the_homepage() {
    pageFactory.getHomePage()
      .get()
      .doSomethingOnTheHomePage()
      .clickSearchWidgetSubmitButton()
      .doSomethingElseOnTheHomePage()      
    ;
  }
}
```

I have a blog post describing this in more detail here: http://blog.jsdevel.me/2015/04/pageobjects-done-right-in-java-8.html

Answer (score 1):

As the [PageObject Selenium help page](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) said "Methods return other PageObjects"